# SubGrid data not displaying in jqGrid 4.4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 4.4.5 with jQuery 1.9.1 and, on the server-side, I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 (though I don't think this is part of the issue).

I have a simple jqGrid working fine, and I am trying to add a simple sub-grid to it.  I have configured the sub-grid, wired it back to a separate controller on the server side and everything seems to work fine, right up to the point where I need to display the sub-grid data.

The initial grid load calls my controller's main data method, gets the json and displays the rows.  Clicking the + sign expands a row, causing a call back to the controller's secondary data method.  The secondary method returns the sub-grid data as valid json (I verified it with the Google Chrome dev tools).  The sub-grid expands and shows the proper number of rows and the correct header, but the values don't appear in the cells.

I have been through the online docs and the various suggestions here but nothing seems to be working.  I have played quite a bit with the jsonReader configuration, but it doesn't seem to help (it doesn't work at all if I set repeatitems to true).  Flipping gridview from true to false doesn't seem to help either.

Any help is appreciated.

This is the actual call made to the sub-grid controller method:

```
/Schedule/SubGridData?nd_=1365975664423&id=1002200&InspectionScheduleId=1002200&ItemTypeId=1000003
```

This is the data Google Chrome claims was returned by the call:

```
{"rows":[{"cell":["Tony\u0027s HomeBrew","Icky Beer"]},{"cell":["Tony\u0027s WorkBrew","Tasty Beer"]}]}
```

This is the grid configuration:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#GridDataBasic').jqGrid({
    autoencode:true,
    autowidth:true,
    caption:'Inspection Schedule',
    datatype:'json',
    jsonReader:{ repeatitems:false, id: 'InspectionScheduleId', subgrid: { root: 'rows', repeatitems: false, cell: 'cell', id: 'id' } },
    emptyrecords:'No record Found',
    gridview:false,
    height:'100%',
    loadui:'block',
    pager:'#pager',
    rowList:[10,15,20,50],
    rowNum:10,
    rowattr: function(rowData) {var dueDate = new Date(parseInt(rowData.DueDate.substr(6)));var nowDate = new Date();var colorDate = new Date(dueDate - (rowData.RedOffsetInMinutes * 60000));if (nowDate > colorDate) { return {'class': 'redOffsetColor'}; }colorDate = new Date(dueDate - (rowData.OrangeOffsetInMinutes * 60000));if (nowDate > colorDate) { return {'class': 'orangeOffsetColor'}; }colorDate = new Date(dueDate - (rowData.YellowOffsetInMinutes * 60000));if (nowDate > colorDate) { return {'class': 'yellowOffsetColor'}; }colorDate = new Date(dueDate - (rowData.GreenOffsetInMinutes * 60000));if (nowDate > colorDate) { return {'class': 'greenOffsetColor'}; }},
    viewsortcols:[true,'vertical',true],
    shrinkToFit:true,
    url:'/Schedule/IndexGridData',
    viewrecords:true,
    subGrid: true,
    subGridUrl : '/Schedule/SubGridData',
    subGridModel : [ { 
    name : [ 'Item Name','Item Description' ],
    width : [ 50,50 ],
    align : [ 'left','left' ],
    params : [ 'InspectionScheduleId','ItemTypeId' ]
     } ],
    colModel: [
    {
      name:'InspectionScheduleId',
      hidden:true,
      key:true,
      label:'InspectionScheduleId',
      sortable:false,
      index:'InspectionScheduleId'
    },{
      name:'ItemTypeId',
      hidden:true,
      label:'ItemTypeId',
      sortable:false,
      index:'ItemTypeId'
    },{
      name:'GreenOffsetInMinutes',
      hidden:true,
      label:'GreenOffsetInMinutes',
      sortable:false,
      index:'GreenOffsetInMinutes'
    },{
      name:'YellowOffsetInMinutes',
      hidden:true,
      label:'YellowOffsetInMinutes',
      sortable:false,
      index:'YellowOffsetInMinutes'
    },{
      name:'OrangeOffsetInMinutes',
      hidden:true,
      label:'OrangeOffsetInMinutes',
      sortable:false,
      index:'OrangeOffsetInMinutes'
    },{
      name:'RedOffsetInMinutes',
      hidden:true,
      label:'RedOffsetInMinutes',
      sortable:false,
      index:'RedOffsetInMinutes'
    },{
      name:'ItemTypeName',
      label:'Item Type',
      sortable:false,
      index:'ItemTypeName'
    },{
      align:'center',
      name:'DueDate',
      formatter:'date', formatoptions: {srcformat:'ISO8601Long', newformat:'m/d/Y H:i:s'},
      label:'Due Date',
      sortable:true,
      index:'DueDate'
    }
    ]
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subgrid` property of `jsonReader` should contain `repeatitems: true` and not `false`. The default value of `subgrid` property is alsready `{root:"rows", repeatitems: true, cell:"cell"}`. So I think that removing `subgrid` property of `jsonReader` should solve your problem.

Comment: SO, that was it *exactly* - thank you.  I got hung up on having the main and sub-grid repeatitems values be the same.  The main grid fails on true, but the sub-grid fails on false.

Comment: @Tony: You are welcome! I'm glad, that I could help you. During answering on questions about `jsonReader` I fond that the usage of it is the source of many errors of newcommer. I posted to trirand suggestions to implement autodetection of JSON format. The suggestions are now a part of jqGrid. I'll look in the code of subgrid to implement the same. If you use jqGrid 4.4.5 you can try to remove full `jsonReader`. There are one bug in usage of `loadonce: true`, but you don't use it. So I think your grid will be successfully filled if you just remove `jsonReader`.

Comment: If I remove jsonReader, though, how will I tell jqGrid which of my columns represents the unique row id?  I don's want jqGrid using an arbitrary value and passing that on any future customization I do.

Comment: @Tony: You use already `key: true` in the definition of the column 'InspectionScheduleId'. It gives jaGrid enough information about id. You can use `jsonReader: {id: 'InspectionScheduleId'}` if you don't have `key: true` defined. You can use Developer Tools of Internet Exploter (press F12 to start) or Google Chrome or use Firebug or other tools to verify that the value of `id` attribute used for <tr> elements is the same as in `'InspectionScheduleId'` column. If you don't plan to show `'InspectionScheduleId'` column then you can *remove* the column and use `jsonReader` with `id` property only.

Answer (score 0):

Your data in the subgrid will not be displayed (as well) if one of your given functions do not exist. So if you make a typo empty lines will be displayed:

```
afterSave: ReloadSubGrid, onError: UpdateFailed, delOptions:...
...
function ReloadSbuGrid(rowid, response) {
    ...
}
```

Typo: ReloadSbuGrid should have been ReloadSubGrid